# Probability same outcome 3 times in a row.

Tags: probability

I am doing some old exam questions - and I don't know the answer, can some one calculate the result and show how you did it?

[image]

Comment: What is the "starting" state?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the probability of getting H on the first throw, Then:
$$
p(HHH)=x\cdot0.7\cdot0.7=0.49x,\qquad
p(TTT)=(1-x)\cdot0.7\cdot0.7=0.49(1-x).
$$
It follows that $p(HHH)+p(TTT)=0.49$.

Comment: Why do you multiple with 0.7?

Comment: Because 70% = 0.7.

Comment: I know. But why do you multiple?

Comment: $p(HH)=p(H)\cdot p(H|H)$, where $p(H|H)=0.7$.

Answer (score 0):

you have to note that the first throw of the coin is independent in the sense that only after knowing the first thow's result will you actually start calculating the probability.so the first throw is certain event so its probility is 1 and now the following two throws have probability 0.7 each.
so (0.7*0.7)*2.

the muliplication by 2 is because the same case can be done whether the first throw comes up h head or tail